# NiFi how to clear all queues

Tags: queue, apache-nifi

I'm currently using NiFi 1.5.0 (but it's the same with the previous versions) and I wonder if there is a way to clear all queues in the same time ?

When the number of processors increase, it can be really long to reset everything.

(I already know how to clear a single queue :
[How to clear NiFi queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785390/how-to-clear-nifi-queues) )

I'm looking for a solution using either the UI or the API

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't had time to test this thoroughly, but it should work:

```
# In your linux shell - NiPyAPI is a Python2/3 SDK for the NiFi API
pip install nipyapi
python
# In Python
from nipyapi import config, canvas, nifi
# Get a flat list of all process groups
pgs = canvas.list_all_process_groups()
# get a flat list of all connections in all process groups
cons = []
for pg in pgs: cons += nifi.ProcessgroupsApi().get_connections(pg.id).connections
# Issue a drop order for every connection in every process group
for con in cons: nifi.FlowfilequeuesApi().create_drop_request(con.id)
```

Edit: I went ahead and implemented this as it seems useful:
https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi/issues/45

```
import nipyapi
pg = nipyapi.canvas.get_process_group('MyProcessGroup')
nipyapi.canvas.purge_process_group(pg, stop=True)
```

The stop option will deschedule the Process Group before purging it, just to be extra handy

Comment: Thanks @Chaffelson, it works perfectly ! I'll take a look to your api

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get rid of all your data completely, you can stop NiFi and remove all of the "_repository" directories (flow file, content, and provenance). This is basically completely resetting your NiFi in terms of data.

Comment: To Bryan's point, to *just* empty the queues, only delete the `flowfile_repository` directory.

Comment: @Bryan I stopped nifi, deleted all the _reponsitories, then restarted nifi but when I pulled up the ui there were still flow files going through processors and queues filling up with data.  How is this possible?

Comment: @ThomasKagan if your source processors are running, then as soon as nifi starts it may be pulling/receiving more date, you'd have to set autoResume=false to avoid this